# how to get back in navigation view using timer

Tags: iphone

hi i am using this code for getting previous view

```
NSTimer *theTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:3.0
                                                  target:self 
                                                selector:@selector(pictureTimerFired:) 
                                                userInfo:nil
                                                 repeats:NO];

- (void) pictureTimerFired:(NSTimer*)theTimer {

NSLog(@"Timer fired, closing picture");
}
```

but what happened is it directly quit from application and displays icon how can i resolve this

Comment: Your application is crashing. Run it with ⌘Y, then look in the console (⇧⌘R) and show us the output.

Answer (score 0):

remove comma from your function name because if your not passing argument to timer then no need to comma and if you are passing argument then use uersInfo at function